# Eyeglasses, spectacles, goggles and glasses. But in which order?

Tags: etymology, history

You would think that finding out if the word *eyeglasses* preceded the word *glasses* would be a simple matter.  Not so. Did *eyeglasses* and *spectacles* as I suspect, precede the word *glasses*? Goggles I presumed came much later but surprisingly the word already existed [in middle English](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=goggle&allowed_in_frame=0).

I found the following information on this [optometrist article](http://optometrist.com.au/people-glasses-spectacles/). Emphasis mine:

> The word ***glasses*** probably developed firstly from the word spyglass,
>   often used for a telescope, and then adapted to “*a pair of eyeglasses*”
>   that needed to be held up to the eyes for full effect.

And on Etymology Online under [spectacles](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=spectacles&searchmode=none) I found:

> **spectacles (n.)** "glass lenses to help a person's sight," early 15c., from plural of
>   spectacle.

While [goggles](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=eyeglasses&searchmode=none) has:

> **goggles**; "spectacles, protective eyeglasses," 1715;

Whereas "[glasses](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=glasses&searchmode=none)" has:

> **glasses**; "spectacles," 1660s, from plural of glass

But I found nothing concrete on eyeglasses strangely enough. Can someone trace the history of the word *glasses*, or provide a chronological order of the words listed in my question?

Comment: @rhetorician thank you for the edit. It sounds much better now.

Comment: Then you have the specialized forms: _quizzing glass_ (by 1801, eyeglass with a handle, for one eye), _lorgnette_ (1803, eyeglasses with a handle, for two eyes), _monocle_ (1858, eyeglass for one eye), and _pince-nez_ (1876, eyeglasses clipped to the nose by a spring).

Comment: Thank you @Sven Yargs, I have never heard of a quizzing glass before. I was hoping someone might trace the history/development of glasses, the post needs "closure" I feel.

Comment: You can see examples at http://mentalfloss.com/article/24320/6-other-types-eyeglasses. That article also lists a French form of eyeglasses called _scissor-glasses_ but I couldn't find any 18th- or 19th-century references in English to this variety, so I didn't include it in my list.

Comment: I think it's an invalid assumption that a word like "glasses" would appear after a word like "eyeglasses". Consider guitars. Before there were electric guitars, there were no "acoustic" guitars, only guitars. Similarly, if "glasses" was understood to generally refer to eyeglass-type lenses, there would be no need for "eye" to precede it. Of course, similar shifts happen the other way as well. These days "computer" doesn't need to be prefaced with "micro-" to refer to the device on your desk.

Comment: I thought "eye-glasses" was a compound word, @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇  which was later shortened to "glasses". But when I searched on the Internet, I didn't find anything concrete, and then by chance I stumbled on goggles and its medieval origins and that is why I asked my question. The OED had the answer, and Andrew Leach very kindly supplied it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's not that it's impossible for words to be formed that way. I'm just pointing out that very often words get longer instead of shorter. It's valid to ask "what came first?", but it's generally not true that compounds come first, then short forms. It happens both ways. There's no way to tell from looking at any pair of words which came first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OED has the following first citations for the sense of lenses to alter vision:

- spectacles: c1430
- glasses: 1545
- goggles: 1715
- eye-glass: 1768

> **eyeglass** *n.*
>   **3b.** In mod. use, a lens of glass or crystal for assisting defective sight. ***double eye-glass, (pair of) eyeglasses :*** two such lenses mounted side by side so as to assist the sight of both eyes; the name is by usage restricted to a pair of lenses to be held in the hand or kept in position by a spring on the nose; those which are secured by pieces of metal placed over the ears being called spectacles.
>
> > 1768   T. Harmer in *Philos. Trans.* 1767 (Royal Soc.) 57 283,   I have often found, by the help of an eye-glass, that..I passed over great multitudes of eggs.

Comment: I (an American) did not know this (presumably UK) distinction between eyeglasses and spectacles.